# HTML Form POST to PHP show a blank page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a newbie to PHP working on an HTML form to submit data to PHP page that is supposed to insert data into MySQL. The form is a simple Registration form. When I click on Submit the URL is redirected but I do not see anything on the page. It's blank. I check the view page source it shows blank as well.

Please let me know if this is the correct way of passing data to PHP. Thank in Advance.

Here is the HTML Page, index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Connection">
    <meta name="author" content="Suman">
    <title>Login or Register </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Scope+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" /> </head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1> Welcome to Connections </h1> </header>
    <section>
        <h2> Already a member. </h2>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <h2> Login </h2> Username
            <br/>
            <input type="email" value="username" name="uname" /> Password
            <br/>
            <input type="password" value="password" name="passwd" />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
        </form>
    </section>
    <section>
        <form action="regusr.php" method="post" >
            <h2> Register </h2> First Name
            <input type="text" value="First Name" name="fname" /> Middle Name
            <input type="text" value="Middle Name" name="mname" /> Last Name
            <input type="text" value="Last Name" name="lname" /> Age
            <input type="number" value="18" name="age" /> 
            Gender<br/>
            Male: <input type="radio" value="1" name="gender" /> Female:<input type="radio" value="2" name="gender"/><br/>
            Email
            <input type="email" value="Email" name="emailid" /> Password
            <input type="password" value="Password" name="passwd" />
            <input type="submit" value="Register" /> 
        </form>
    </section>
    <footer> For any queries please contact us
        <br /> Phone: +91-40-460870000 ext:1234
        <br /> email: admin@gmail.com
        <br /> For any issue with the web site please send an email to webmaster@gmail.com
        <br/> &copy; Copyright All rights reserved.
        <br /> </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the PHP page - regusr.php

```
 <? php    

    //Get the user info from the form
    $uname = $_POST['emailid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['passwd'];
    $first = $_POST['fname'];
    $middle = $_POST['mname'];
    $last = $_POST['lname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    echo "username:" .$uname ."passwd:" .$pwd ."first:" .$first ."middle:" .$middle ."last:" .$last ."age:" .$age ."gender:" .$gender;

    include("config.php");
    // Check connection
    if (!$db) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO userid (userid, user_name, user_paswd) VALUES ('$uname', '$pwd')";
    $insert = mysqli_query($db, $sqlinsert);
    if(!$insert){
        printf("Error in insert query:%s\n",$insert->error)
    }

    mysqli_free_result($insert);

    $sqlquery = "SELECT userid from userid where user_name='$uname'"
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sqlquery);
    $id = 0;
    //We should be having only a single item from the query
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $id = $row[0];
            break;
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        $datainsert = "INSERT INTO user_data (user_id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, age, sex, userid_fk ) 
        VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$middle', '$age', '$gender', '$id')";
    } else {
        echo "Database Error could not insert data.";
    }

        <h1>Basic Info</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name: </td>
                <td> <?php echo $first ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Middle Name: </td>
                <td> <?php echo $middle ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name: </td>
                <td> <?php echo $last ?> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
?>
```

Comment: Have you enabled `display_errors`?

Comment: on php page just after starting `<?php` write `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and check once again by posting the form data

Comment: Also... You should hash your users password and use parameterized queries. This is open to SQL injections.

Comment: just echo  $uname = $_POST['emailid']; exit; and check value of username

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

**PHP Code**

```
    <?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "team44";
    $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

    // Check connection
    if (!$db) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        //Get the user info from the form
        $uname = $_POST['emailid'];
        $pwd = $_POST['passwd'];
        $first = $_POST['fname'];
        $middle = $_POST['mname'];
        $last = $_POST['lname'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];

        echo "username:" . $uname . "passwd:" . $pwd . "first:" . $first . "middle:" . $middle . "last:" . $last . "age:" . $age . "gender:" . $gender;

        //Login
        $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO userid (userid, user_name, user_paswd) VALUES (NULL, '$uname', '$pwd')";

        // Registation
        $datainsert = "INSERT INTO user_data (user_id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, age, sex, userid_fk ) VALUES (NULL,'".$first."', '".$last."', '".$middle."', '".$age."', '".$gender."', '".$id."')";
        $insert = mysqli_query($db, $sqlinsert);
        $regi = mysqli_query($db, $datainsert);

        if (!$insert || !$regi ) {
            printf("Error in insert query:%s\n", $insert->error);
        }else{
  header('location:login.php);
}
    }
    ?>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Connection">
        <meta name="author" content="Suman">
        <title>Login or Register </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Scope+One" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" /> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1> Welcome to Connections </h1> 
        </header>
        <section>
            <h2> Already a member. </h2>
            <form action="login.php" method="post">
                <h2> Login </h2> Username
                <br/>
                <input type="email" value="username" name="uname" /> Password
                <br/>
                <input type="password" value="password" name="passwd" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
            </form>
        </section>
        <section>
            <form method="POST" >
                <h2> Register </h2> First Name
                <input type="text" value="First Name" name="fname" /> Middle Name
                <input type="text" value="Middle Name" name="mname" /> Last Name
                <input type="text" value="Last Name" name="lname" /> Age
                <input type="number" value="18" name="age" /> 
                Gender<br/>
                Male: <input type="radio" value="1" name="gender" /> Female:<input type="radio" value="2" name="gender"/><br/>
                Email
                <input type="email" value="Email" name="emailid" /> Password
                <input type="password" value="Password" name="passwd" />
                <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" /> 
            </form>
        </section>
        <footer> For any queries please contact us
            <br /> Phone: +91-40-460870000 ext:1234
            <br /> email: admin@gmail.com
            <br /> For any issue with the web site please send an email to webmaster@gmail.com
            <br/> &copy; Copyright All rights reserved.
            <br /> </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this code but does not work. Look like there is a different issue. I tried to do a simple Echo on the PHP page but I do not see anything there.You can check this link [link](http://lynkuz.com/demo/index.html) I have uploaded the code here.

Comment: @SumanMummaneni Please check it now, I have updated this code

Comment: Just copy and past and change the connection string.

Comment: Thank you for the code but this still did not work on my website. After searching the web I found the issue. I was not selecting the data I had to add this  <code>'mysql_select_db('schema name');' </code>. I was able to insert into the table.

Comment: I also found one more think from my ISP, they are using PHP 5.4 and above. The PHP is configured not use register_globals by setting it off. Is there any better way to handle code so that it work if I move to other PHP version, I do not have to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your regusr.php file you create nested php.  Have you check this out?  You should close you php tag before writing html. If you are not doing this, then you should write html inside echo. for example,

```
echo "<h1>Hello, World</h1>"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer...**

Once try it

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "team44";
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$db) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    //Get the user info from the form
    $uname = $_POST['emailid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['passwd'];
    $first = $_POST['fname'];
    $middle = $_POST['mname'];
    $last = $_POST['lname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    echo "username:" . $uname . "passwd:" . $pwd . "first:" . $first . "middle:" . $middle . "last:" . $last . "age:" . $age . "gender:" . $gender;

    //Login
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO userid (userid, user_name, user_paswd) VALUES (null, '$uname', '$pwd')";

    // Registation
    $datainsert = "INSERT INTO user_data (user_id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, age, sex, userid_fk ) VALUES ('".$first."', '".$last."', '".$middle."', '".$age."', '".$gender."', '".$id."')";
    $insert = mysqli_query($db, $sqlinsert);
    $regi = mysqli_query($db, $datainsert);

    if (!$insert || !$regi ) {
        printf("Error in insert query:%s\n", $insert->error);
    }
}

?>

<h1>Basic Info</h1>
<table>
    <tr>      
        <th>First Name:</th>
        <th>Middle Name:</th>
        <th>Last Name:</th>       
    </tr>
    <?php
    $sqlquery = "SELECT * from userid where user_name=".$uname;
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sqlquery);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
        <td> <?php echo $row['first']; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['middel']; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['last']; ?> </td>   
    <?php } ?>
</table>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Connection">
        <meta name="author" content="Suman">
        <title>Login or Register </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Scope+One" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" /> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1> Welcome to Connections </h1> 
        </header>
        <section>
            <h2> Already a member. </h2>
            <form action="login.php" method="post">
                <h2> Login </h2> Username
                <br/>
                <input type="email" value="username" name="uname" /> Password
                <br/>
                <input type="password" value="password" name="passwd" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
            </form>
        </section>
        <section>
            <form action="regusr.php" method="post" >
                <h2> Register </h2> First Name
                <input type="text" value="First Name" name="fname" /> Middle Name
                <input type="text" value="Middle Name" name="mname" /> Last Name
                <input type="text" value="Last Name" name="lname" /> Age
                <input type="number" value="18" name="age" /> 
                Gender<br/>
                Male: <input type="radio" value="1" name="gender" /> Female:<input type="radio" value="2" name="gender"/><br/>
                Email
                <input type="email" value="Email" name="emailid" /> Password
                <input type="password" value="Password" name="passwd" />
                <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" /> 
            </form>
        </section>
        <footer> For any queries please contact us
            <br /> Phone: +91-40-460870000 ext:1234
            <br /> email: admin@gmail.com
            <br /> For any issue with the web site please send an email to webmaster@gmail.com
            <br/> &copy; Copyright All rights reserved.
            <br /> </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not want to mix my PHP and HTML code unless it's necessary to do it that way.

Answer (score -1):

You are using 3 fileds  (userid, user_name, user_paswd) but only 2 values (uname and pwd) .its not going to insert into userid table

values should be like   VALUES ('$uname','$uname', '$pwd')";

```
"INSERT INTO userid (userid, user_name, user_paswd) VALUES ('$userid','$uname', '$pwd')";
```

Plese check this too (user id is missing):

```
"INSERT INTO user_data (user_id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, age, sex, userid_fk ) 
        VALUES ('$userid','$first', '$last', '$middle', '$age', '$gender', '$id')";
```

Comment: How do he get $userid?

Comment: @dhruv jadia I am not posted exact answer .I am just suggested him that there is an error in his query . Without clearing this error .values not going to insert to the table .

Comment: yes but you don't have to set value for auto-increment field just pass it to null